# Change TOC to use underline in subsubsections

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, capitalization, text-decorations

I am using the package `memoir` and I need to redefine the fonts in TOC with this  rules:

- For Chapters: *all-caps* and *bold*
- For Sections: *bold*
- For SubSections: *bold* and *italic*
- For SubSubSections: *bold* and *underline*
- For SubSubSubSections: *nothing to do*

I had success to configure `sections`:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\bfseries}
```

`subsections`:

```
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionfont}{\bfseries\itshape}
```

But for `chapters`, I didn't  have success to use `\MakeUppercase`:

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\MakeUppercase\bfseries}
```

and for `subsubsections`, I didn't have success to put  on underline

```
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\bfseries\underline}
```

So, how I put underline and uppercase?

Answer (score 5):

`\MakeUppercase` and `\underline` are not font declarations. One has to work harder to achieve the result you want and that, personally, I don't like at all.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@chapapp}
  {\cftchapterfont #1}
  {\cftchapterfont\MakeUppercase{#1}}
  {}{}

\patchcmd{\l@subsubsection}
  {#1}
  {\ric@subunderline{#1}}
  {}{}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \ifnum\value{secnumdepth}>\tw@
    \def\ric@subunderline#1{\ric@@subunderline#1\@nil}
    \def\ric@@subunderline#1#2#3\@nil{#1{#2}\underline{#3}}
  \else
    \def\ric@subunderline#1{\underline{#1}}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

%%% Fonts
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionfont}{\bfseries\itshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\bfseries}

\settocdepth{subsubsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\chapter{Some title}
\section{Some title}
\subsection{Some title}
\subsubsection{Some title}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hum, but when I use `hyperref` package this solution didn't work. hyperref is incompatible with this?

Comment: @Ric With `hyperref` it's really a different matter, I'm afraid.

Comment: `\MakeUppercase` only works on simple text. When `hyperref` is added the hyperlink is added before `\MakeUppercase` gains access to it, thus is becomes too complicated for `\MakeUppercase`. The next `memoir` will have a workaround for this particular example (for `\chapter`, `\part` and`\book`)

Answer (score 3):

Here is to achieve what you want, maintaining `hyperref` compatibility:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%%% to check compatibility
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%% re-styling the TOC with etoc:
\usepackage{etoc}
\makeatletter
\let\old@chapter\l@chapter
\let\old@chapternumberline\chapternumberline
\etocsetstyle{chapter}{}{}
     {\old@chapter{\old@chapternumberline{\etocnumber}%
                       \etoclink{\MakeUppercase\etocthename}}{\etocpage}}{}%
\let\old@section\l@section
\etocsetstyle{section}{}{}
     {\old@section{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}%
\let\old@subsection\l@subsection
\etocsetstyle{subsection}{}{}
     {\old@subsection{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}{}%
\let\old@subsubsection\l@subsubsection
\etocsetstyle{subsubsection}{}{}
     {\old@subsubsection{\numberline{\etocnumber}\underline{\etocname}}{\etocpage}}{}%
\makeatother

%%% Fonts
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsectionfont}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsectionfont}{\bfseries\itshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\bfseries}

\settocdepth{subsubsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\chapter{Some title}
\section{Some title}
\subsection{Some title}
\subsubsection{Some title}
\end{document}
```

[image: eTOC]