# Incompatibility of \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} with \titlecontents{section}{\thecontentslabel\quad}{\underline}{}{\hfill\thecontentspage}

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, titletoc

The following (other than the `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`) is taken from [User math's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169554/67761) in [Underline the section title text in table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169553/underline-the-section-title-text-in-table-of-contents).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
% The line below seems to be incompatible with the underlining of the line beneath it
% \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\titlecontents{section}{\thecontentslabel\quad}{\underline}{}{\hfill\thecontentspage}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Foobar}
\end{document}
```

If one un-comments the commented line of code, one can not have both `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}`, and have the underlining working at the same time.

I wonder why, and whether there is a way to circumvent this, without resorting to the `soul`package (as had done [User math in his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169554/67761); and others; in the mentioned OP), thus by still using the 2 currently incompatible lines up to a great extent at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no incompatibility, only errors in the syntax for `\titlecontents`.

The first argument is for code *preceding* the section label. Furthermore, there an optional-mandatory argument, which is the distance form the left margin. Also, don't use `\underline` here: you might have long titles, and `\underline` does not break across lines. Use `\ul` from `soul(utf8)` instead.

*Edit:*

However, there *is* an incompatibility if using `hyperref. I added a  hack, due to Heiko Oberbiek, to circumvent the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{soulutf8} % The line below seems to be incompatible with the underlining of the line beneath it
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\makeatletter
\def\myul#1{%
\ulxxx#1\@ulxxxend
}%
\def\ulxxx\hyper@linkstart#1#2#3\hyper@linkend\@ulxxxend{%
\hyper@linkstart{#1}{#2}{\ul{#3}}\hyper@linkend
}%
\makeatother

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\titlecontents{section}[0em]{}{\thecontentslabel\quad\myul}{\myul}{\hfill\contentspage}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Foobar. A quite long, long section title. A still longer, longer, longer subsection title}
Some test.
\newpage

\section{Another, shorter, section}
Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This answer is incompatible with `\usepackage{hyperref}` though...

Comment: Could you explain in what way it is incompatible?

Comment: If you add that line (`\usepackage{hyperref}`) in your MWE, then it is no longer compilable (I'm on *Texshop*, using *LaTeX* as a *Program*, where it still compiles once, but not twice and more). I get the following error, from the **.toc**: `\hyper@linkstart has an extra }`.

Comment: @Vincent Verheyen: Problem solved (Heiko Oberdiek's hack)! Please take a look at my updated answer.