# TOC title and capital letter problem

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to format my thesis to university requirements. My university requires;

- Contents title (Page & TOC) must write with capital letters.
- Second or Third Page of toc title must be "İçindekiler (devam)".
- subsubsection must be underlined in toc

I can't add title to toc's second or third page. For capital letter problem this is my code.

```
\addto\captionturkish{%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}%
   {İÇİNDEKİLER}%
}
\tableofcontents
```

[image]

I'm working on overleaf.

Edit :

Second Page of TOC(No Title):
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "cant add title to toc's second page"?  Maybe a MWE would be helpful, too. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169553/underline-the-section-title-text-in-table-of-contents

Comment: I added second page of toc to question.

Comment: I solved underline problem with this command.
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\underline}
Thank you :)

Comment: Solved the capital letter problem with
\renewcommand\contentsname{İÇİNDEKİLER}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `\addto\captionturkish`, it should be added in the preamble instead. If you're adding code immediately before `\tableofcontents`, then `\renewcommand{\contentsname}{...}` will do.

For the title/heading after the first page of the `\tableofcontents`, here's a solution inspired by https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72991/226:

```
%%% IN THE PREAMBLE
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AtBeginShipoutClear}{\gdef\AtBegShi@Hook{}}
\makeatother

%%% IN THE DOCUMENT BODY
\AtBeginShipout{\textbf{İÇİNDEKİLER (Devam)}\par}
\tableofcontents
\AtBeginShipoutClear    % Clears the heading
```

You can repeat this similarly with `\listoffigures`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For Contents title (Page & TOC) must write with capital letters.

```
\renewcommand\contentsname{İÇİNDEKİLER}
```

For Second or Third Page of toc title must be "İçindekiler (devam)".

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\chapter*{İÇİNDEKİLER (Devam)}}
```

if you want to add title to list of figures

```
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\chapter*{ŞEKİLLER DİZİNİ (Devam)}}
```

For subsubsection must be underlined in toc

```
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsectionfont}{\underline}
```